# php convert.quoted-printable-decode kills script

Tags: php

This code completly kills php, no errors, no warning. How catch or skip this?

```
$param = ['line-break-chars' => "\r\n"];
$handle = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
stream_filter_append($handle, 'convert.quoted-printable-decode', 
 STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $param);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "=\" /></p>\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "   a\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
```

I use this (above) filter to filter the data stream. I reconstructed special string that kills my script.

My PHP version is 7.2

Edit:

After entering the script, server returns error `504`.

php.ini settings

```
display_errors: On
error_reporting: 32767 //(E_ALL)
```

Comment: Can you please also share your error settings in php.ini?

Comment: Ok, I added information about error settings.

Comment: The error you should be getting (run it on the CLI when it fails via webserver) is `PHP Warning:  fwrite(): stream filter (convert.quoted-printable-decode): invalid byte sequence`. And that's most likely because the stream filter is for decoding. None of your `fwrite` calls contain any quoted printable escapes to begin with.

Comment: After run in CLI I see warnings (invalid byte sequence) and at end Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: That's to be expected when it enters an unclean state. See also [How do I diagnose this PHP segmentation fault?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13079513) to figure out details, if needed. (I'd think it's more the stream convert. wrapper than the [qp_decode](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8d3f8ca12a0b00f2a74a27424790222536235502/ext/standard/quot_print.c))